# Как начать делать текстовый квест?

Tags: c#

Нужно реализовать класс Quest в котором будут хранятся шаги.

Шаги представляют собой класс с каким-то текстом и вариантами выбора. Пользователь сам добавляет шаги и варианты выбора, которые в свою очереди ведут к следующим шагам (сценам) в зависимости от выбора игрока. Как я понимаю каждый выбор должен иметь ссылку на следующий шаг (сцену). Но как это реализовать в коде не понимаю.

Comment: "...допустим 3 выбора и при каком-то выборе переходит на следующий шаг." Это как? Может нужно выбирать один раз из трех вариантов? И каждый вариант ведет к той или иной ветке развития сюжета? Вам нужно переформулировать вопрос более понятным образом.

Comment: @Bulson все в точности как Вы описали, я не понимаю как сделать переход на следующую развилку сюжета

Comment: Ну, то, что вы описали, похоже на стейт-машину.

Comment: @VladD, там и до компилятора не далеко :-)

Comment: Если Вы хотите сделать именно игру, то могу посоветовать Вам готовые решения - `Renpy`(на `python`) для создания визуальных новелл, если же хочется `C#`, то `Unity3D`(лично использовал ассет `Fungus` для создания визуальной новеллы).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В общем, [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) абсолютно прав, вам нужен конечный автомат (в английской терминологии state machine), и желательно разобраться что это такое подробнее, но я попробую показать простой для понимания пример не используя пока специфическую терминологию.

Вам попадались книги-игры [Дмитрия Браславского](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)? В прочем если бы попадались, вопрос бы не возник.

И так, что такое текстовый квест? Это набор параграфов, описывающих некоторые игровые сцены в которых игроку требуется принять некоторое решение, чтобы перейти к другой сцене. Ок, от этого и пойдем.

1. Пронумеруем все параграфы в произвольном порядке. Для книги нумерация имеет значение, для компьютерного варианта - нет.
2. Размещаем параграфы в массив согласно сделанной нумерации.
3. Каждый выбор игрока, фактически, означает выбор следующего параграфа, но выбор в слепую, т.к. игрок не знает содержимое параграфа (во всяком случае в первой игре). Таким образом, необходимо сопоставить предлагаемые игроку действия на текущей сцене с номерами параграфов на который они ведут.
4. Когда игрок сделал свой выбор, мы просто показываем ему текст следующего параграфа с соответствующим индексом в массиве и ожидаем следующего выбора игрока, разумеется если это выбор у него есть в данной сцене.

Естественно возможен вариант, когда игрок может попасть на одну и туже сцену (параграф) разными путями.

Таким  образом, вам достаточно одного единственного класса для описания модели вашего квеста, при этом ни чего мудреного не требуется. Для консольного варианта достаточно базовых знаний C#: синтаксис, условия, массивы, циклы. ну и немного стандартных классов для организации ввода/вывода.

В эту модель прекрасно вписывается и "боевка" с бросанием кубиков, и применение ранее приобретенных вещей, если сцена предполагает возможность их применения.

Какую к данной модели приделать "шкурку": консоль, или развесистый графический интерфейс с иллюстрациями и музыкой, не имеет значения, т.к. самое сложное в данном типе игр - создать сюжет и написать тексты игровых сцен, чтобы они не были все на одно лицо.

Единственное что я бы посоветовал лично от себя - не показывайте игроку настоящие номера параграфов, спрячьте их за кнопками с текстом, локальными номерами (1,2,3 и т.д. по количеству вариантов выбора в сцене) для консоли, ссылками для Web-версии. Так интереснее, и больше вероятность, что игрок хотя бы прочитает (а может и запомнит) текст над которым вы или ваш сценарист трудились, создавая квест.

---

Ну и немного кода для иллюстрации возможной (но не единственной) реализации такой модели:

Простейший вариант для консоли с одним классом:

```
class Quest
{
    public string[] Paragraphs {get; set;}
    public int[][] Choises {get; set;}
    //Для консольного варианта вы просто отображаете номера для выбора прямо в тексте
    //параграфа, рядом с описанием выбора, как в книжном варианте.
}
```

Более сложный пример:

```
class Paragraph //параграф (игровая сцена)
{
    public int Num {get; set;}//не особо нужен, но для полной картины пусть будет
    public string Text {get; set;}
    //доступные варианты, список может быть нулевой длины, но не null.
    public List<Choise> Choises {get;} = new List<Choise>();
} 

class Choise
{
    public int NextParagraph {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;} //текст варианта выбора для игрока
} 

class Quest
{
    Paragraph Current {get; set;}
    //Если номера параграфов соответствуют индексам можно так
    List<Paragraph> {get;} = new List<Paragraph>();
    //Если лень следить за соответствием - так
    Dictionary<int, Paragraph> {get;} = new Dictionary<int, Paragraph>();
}
```

Если знаете что такое направленный граф, то можно еще проще

```
class Paragraph //параграф (игровая сцена)
{
    public string Text {get; set;} //текст параграфа
    //доступные варианты, список может быть нулевой длины, но не null.
    public List<Choise> Choises {get;} = new List<Choise>();
} 

class Choise
{
    public Paragraph Next {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;} //текст варианта выбора для игрока
} 

class Quest
{
    Paragraph Current {get; set;}
    Paragraph StartPoint {get; set;};
}
```

С кодом ввода выбора игрока и вывода текста на экран, думаю сами справитесь.

Comment: Как минимум 2 сущности будет все же: параграф (его номер и текст) и переход (номер параграфа из которого переходим, номер куда переходим, текст выбора) и между ними связь один ко многим. В один и тот же параграф можно попасть из разных мест, но текст выбора будет разный, поэтому многие ко многим связь не нужна. Ну и хранить все это лучше в простенькой бд. EF подойдёт очень хорошо и должно всё пойти гладко, т к по сути мы из бд будем только читать

Comment: @Андрей, т.е. вы предлагаете к игре, которую можно сделать даже на spectrum, прикрутить ынтерпрайзного монстра EF? Вы серьёзно думаете что от этого будет профит? Я даже со словарями перегнул, обычных массивов достаточно, т.к. контент фиксирован и доступ по индексу

Comment: А текст параграфов захардкодить в коде программы?

Comment: @Андрей, зачем в коде, в отдельном текстовом файле

Comment: Ну можно не EF, конечно, я погорячился, а просто ADO.NET и какой-нибудь `Dapper`. Да и `Dapper` не нужен-то по сути, пару-тройку полей можно уж и вручную замаппить.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, какой нибудь пример с кодом. Я не понимаю где хранить текст(описание) действие для выбора

Comment: @Влад чуть расширил код модели, ну а внутреннюю логику уже сами пишите, тут и так почти весь необходимый код уже есть, кроме обвязочного ввода/вывода

Comment: Интересно еще как реализовать действия "волшебных" объектов, как в книге (которые действовали как номер параграфа + какое-то число). Наверное в параграфе, где этот предмет может подействовать, должны быть скрытые переходы, активные только при наличии предмета.

Comment: @insolor в общем да. В некоторых сценах такие предметы работали, в некоторых нет, ну и нумерация параграфов выходит на ключевые позиции. Если вы о программной реализации, то да, скрытые переходы, активные только при наличии предмета, все как в книжках =)

Comment: @rdorn спасибо Вам большое, а то вообще не понимал как начать делать