# Как сделать текстовый квест на C#

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Как сделать текстовый квест на C# , обьясните пожалуйста что для этого нужно сам не понимаю недавно начал изучение и вот хочу сделать но не понимаю как.

Comment: Изучить язык, на котором пишете, продумать этот самый квест, ну и написать.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, и язык программирования тут ни при чём

Comment: Язык - инструмент, как молоток, чтобы забить гвоздь. Вы можете выбрать понрааившийся молоток, но если вы не определитесь, что за гвоздь вам надо забить, куда, и, самое главное - зачем? У вас вряд-ли что-то получится. Для реализации игр с помощью C# многие используют движок Unity. Примеров много можно найти, разных, видео тоже.

Comment: Посмотрите, к примеру, этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703125

Answer (score 2):

Хоть это и неприлично, но я предположу, что вы вообще в программировании только начинаете разбираться, а не только в C#, иначе у вас навряд ли возник бы такой вопрос в такой формулировке. Исходя из этого, я хочу дать вам субъективный совет-алгоритм:

1. Напишите хоть что-то. Если вы будете долго думать о том, как сделать идеальную игру, то вскоре потеряете все желание что-то делать. Начните, к примеру, с ввода-вывода из консоли и кучи условий.
2. Попробуйте сами поиграть в свою игру, прочувствуйте, что вам не нравится, что вы хотите добавить, после чего просто реализуйте свои желания - вы сами хозяин своей игры. Тут у вас появятся конкретные вопросы по реализации, которые вполне приветствуются и тут, и на других форумах.
3. Далее вы заметите, что вам неудобно что-то исправлять в своем коде и читать его через некоторый промежуток времени. На этом шаге вам стоит ненадолго засесть за учебники, чтобы улучшить саму структуру своей игры. (Это также является одним из самых лучших (имхо) способов выучить ООП и паттерны).
4. Скорее всего, вы просто не захотите продолжать свою игру, пытаясь интегрировать в нее только что выученные приемы. Тут вам стоит просто перейти к шагу 1, начав разработку новой игры, используя в ней все то, что вы выучили на третьем шаге.

Конкретно насчет текстовых квестов: если вас интересует именно создание истории, а не тонкости реализаций, то вам стоит посмотреть в сторону готовых движков и мейкеров.